# « Je suis sûr », « je suis certain », « je suis sûr et certain » : différences

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, synonymes

Y a-t-il des différences entre « je suis sûr », « je suis certain » et « je suis sûr et certain » ?

Quand peut-on utiliser chaque tournure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilisés comme attributs du sujet, les adjectifs ***sûr*** et ***certain*** sont quasiment synonymes.

Il existe une petite nuance, *certain* est plus fort que *sûr* car la certitude et plus indiscutable, elle s'appuie souvent sur une preuve ou une démonstration, alors que *sûr* s'appuie plus sur un sentiment, une impression, une assurance qui est plus personnelle, intuitive que générale.

Quant à ***sûr et certain***, il s'agit d'une locution figée<sup>1</sup> qui combine les deux sens. *Je suis sûr et certain* signifie *je suis intimement convaincu de la véracité de la chose en question (sûr), et rien ne permet d'en douter* (certain).

> *Je suis sûr qu'il a raison*  → C'est ma conviction.

> *Je suis certain qu'il a raison* → Il y a des preuves.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>On ne dit jamais ***je suis certain et sûr***.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**I**

On utilise « je/tu/… suis/es/… sûr » presque toujours avec un complément. Cette construction est très fréquente lorsque le complément est « en ». ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+suis+s%C3%BBr%2Cj%27en+suis+s%C3%BBr&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20s%C3%BBr%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cj%27en%20suis%20s%C3%BBr%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20s%C3%BBr%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cj%27en%20suis%20s%C3%BBr%3B%2Cc0))

[image]

On utilise parfois cette forme sans complément mais rarement : [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+suis+s%C3%BBr.%2Cje+suis+s%C3%BBr&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20s%C3%BBr%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20s%C3%BBr%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20s%C3%BBr%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20suis%20s%C3%BBr%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Cette locutions se construit avec des compléments qui sont des propositions introduites par la conjonction de subordination « que », des propositions infinitives introduites par « de », et avec groupes prépositionnels introduits par « de », sauf quand ce complément est « en ».

- Il est sûr **d**'avoir un cadeaux.
- Je suis sûr **qu**'il va décrocher le pompon.
- Je suis sûr **de** sa foi.
- Elle est sûre **que** non.
- Ils sont sûr **d**'arriver à la montagne demain.
- Vous êtes sûre **de** pouvoir finir ce tricot ?

**II**

« Je/tu/… suis/es/… certain » est un synonyme de « je suis sûr » et s'emploie de la même façon.

**III**

Lorsqu'on combine les deux locutions on ne fait pas autre chose que d'assurer que ce dont on est sûr ne peut  être contredit en aucun cas. « Sûr et certain » signifie donc « très sûr » ou « très, très sûr ».